# problem with task switcher and ccsm

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm trying to make a simpler task switcher work, instead of the default with unity.

I installed ccsm, and then the extras to be able to access to Static Application Switcher.

The problem right now is that I can enable Static Application Switcher but only if I run ccsm as sudo.

When I try to enable running ccsm without sudo it doesn't let me enable anything. All the checkboxes are disabled.

And enabling as sudo doesn't make the task switcher work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: With static task switcher,did you mean Static Application Switcher in CCSM?

Comment: yes, sorry, now I edit the question

Comment: Nowadays I can't modify my compiz settings, cos I don't want to break my system's stability. But maybe, you can use Super+W key in order to make best switch and you can set the screen corner settings in Ubuntu Tweak to start window switching.This advice won't solve your problem but you can like it.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed is to reboot after install the compiz extras, now it works fine and now I have a simplier app switcher working.